# Transform more than 1 dynamic xml Files via XSLT into one xml/resx file in C#

Tags: c#, transform, xslt, resx

I want to transform one or more dynamic resx/xml files via xslt to one resx/xml file.
The code should run in VisualStudio 2010

My idea was this code:

```
XsltSettings set = new XsltSettings(true, false);  
set.EnableDocumentFunction = true;

        XElement root = new XElement("root",
            XElement.Load("file1.xml"),
            XElement.Load("file2.xml"));

        XslCompiledTransform transform = new XslCompiledTransform();
        transform.Load("xsl.xsl",set,new XmlUrlResolver());
        XsltArgumentList xslArg = new XsltArgumentList();
        transform.Transform(root.CreateReader(), /*xslArg,*/ XmlWriter.Create("output.xml"));
```

I look gratefully for answers

Comment: 1) Are you looking for help writing the xslt, or help with getting the two input files into one? 2) What was the result of your idea - did it work? were there errors? incorrect results? Not ready to run yet? If the latter, at what point are you stuck?

Comment: I want to transform >=2 resx files into one resx file and extract specified data from the two files.  Error: "InvalidOperationException was unhandled" --> Result would be an invalid XML-Document

Comment: I don't see here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.xelement.aspx a p/3 constructor...

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void MergeResx(XElement target, string[] sources)
    {

        foreach (string source in sources)
        {
            XElement xe = XElement.Load(source);
            target.Add(new XElement("InternalRoot", new XAttribute("Source", source), from el in xe.Elements()
                                                                                      select el));
        }
        target.Save(@"C:\MergeDone.xml");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is about as good as you will get without writing an extension for the XSLT processor.  You might also consider just using LINQ to XML to recompose the documents.